# How to show CustomAction on a certain Custom List

Tags: sharepoint, custom-lists, custom-action, list-definition

How can I show a `CustomAction` for a List of "Custom List" type and it's Title is "Demo List"?
Is this possible? if not is there any workaround to achieve what I want?